# How to access Nuxt JS data() from transition?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm having difficulty in accessing the data object in Nuxt JS via the transition function, has anyone else had this problem? I've tried defining `this` as `self` and accessing a `computed` property as well, neither of which seem to work:

```
export default {
  transition (to, from) {
    if (from) {
      return to.params.id < from.params.id ? `slide-left-${this.hasSwipeSpeed}` : `slide-right-${this.hasSwipeSpeed}`
    } else {
      return `slide-left-${this.hasSwipeSpeed}`
    }
  }
}
```

`this.hasSwipeSpeed` is defined in `data()`, but I don't appear to have access to this from within `transition`

Answer (score 0):

According to the Vue lifecycle hooks, the data doesn't exists yet because transition will be called before created hook (you could see this by using debugger in both functions). So, simply set "SwipeSpeed" without using data.

Comment: Right, this is inconvenient then :D how would I access the `$store` as this is technically where I need to pull some data from. I'm using vuex with a computed property, I need access to: `his.$store.state.localStorage.settings.swipeSpeed`

Comment: Nothing is defined, e.g: `this.$store`, `this.$refs`, `this.$route`, even if I add a `var testVar = 'hello world'` into either `created, mounted, beforeCreate` it's all undefined.

Comment: localStorage alone is accessible here, but $store no. So, you could use localStorage